# Applying for German Study Visa with past visa refusal

Tags: germany, visa-refusals, schengen-visas, study

I am from Pakistan. I applied for a study visa to the UK in 2022, which was refused due to false information. Now I am applying for German study visa, which requires which has this requirement in it. Is it now necessary to show the past refusal etc. and if not shown what are the consequences?

[image]

Comment: The application form asks for details about previous refusals. Why do you even consider that it may not be necessary to answer that point in the visa application? I ask because I never understand why such questions are even necessary.

Comment: Why was false info submitted the first time?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo, here are some thoughts that people may have: UK is not in the Schengen zone so Germany should not not care; my application will be scrutinized more thoroughly with higher chances of refusal if I do provide information; I threw away all the documents related to refusal so cannot provide them anymore; etc.

Answer (score 2):

A refusal for the production of false information in the UK usually automatically leads to a UK visa ban for 10 years for deception (Immigration rules 320 (7a/7b))

This is an **extremely bad thing** and really hurts your credibility but **doesn't** prevent you to get a visa elsewhere, it is just going to be extremely hard

> Is it now necessary to show the past refusal etc.

It is not in the [application form](https://pakistan.diplo.de/blob/1673154/f9342033f2933dc05da54151efe283db/application-longterm-data.pdf), but yes, you need to follow the list of documents required and join the refusal letter for your UK visa

> and if not shown what are the consequences?

A lot can happen, they may :

- refuse you for deception again, which will put your refusal in the Visa Information System, letting all other Schengen members know about your refusal for five years.

> > Only the following categories of data shall be recorded in the VIS:
>
> on the applicant for a long-stay visa or a residence permit and on long-stay visas and residence permits requested, issued, refused, withdrawn, revoked, annulled, extended or renewed as referred to in Article 22a and Articles 22c to 22f;

[Visa Information System](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=uriserv%3AOJ.L_.2021.248.01.0011.01.ENG&toc=OJ%3AL%3A2021%3A248%3ATOC)

- If they hear about your deception after issuing the visa, they can and very likely will, revoke your visa/residence permit and make you leave/deport you from Germany, which will make your life a lot harder

> A foreigner can be expelled if he or she has furnished false or incomplete information in order to gain a German residence permit or a Schengen visa.
> The applicant is obliged to provide all information to the best of his or her knowledge and belief. If he or she refuses to provide data or knowingly furnishes false or incomplete information, the visa application may be refused or, if a visa has already been issued, the applicant may be expelled from Germany.
> In signing this document, the applicant certifies that, before submitting the application, he or she was informed of the legal consequences of refusing to provide data or furnishing false or incomplete information in the visa application process.

*From the application form*

---

Don't try to stack deception on deception, this is **not** a good thing.

Having a visa refusal usually doesn't mean that all other visas will be denied, you just need to be honest about it